# How to create a custom framework with Xcode For iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

How to create a custom framework with Xcode and use it with iOS Application ?

Answer (score -1):

This may help: [Universal Framework iPhone iOS](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/)

Comment: thanks for the tutorial but it wasn't clear enough , I have already saw it .